# Спарсить url из строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую!

Есть строка:

```
var str = 'Hello, Alexey, let's go to http://duckhub.ru, or https://belinux.ru ?';
```

Цель :  Заменить ссылки на `<a href='http://duckhub.ru'></a>`.

Comment: и с чем у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Не пойму как...

Comment: попробуйте использовать **регулярные выражения**

Comment: Использование регулярных выражений для парсинга url'ов —
 неоднозначное и весьма трудоемкое решение. Посмотрите [обсуждение аналогичной задачи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) (англ.), там же предлагают несколько библиотек для парсинга строк на предмет поиска в них url'ов.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /(https?:\/\/)([^/.]*)([.ru]*)/gi;
var str = "Hello, Alexey, let's go to http://duckhub.ru, or https://belinux.ru ?";
var newstr = str.replace(reg, "<a href='http://duckhub.ru'></a>");
```